# Converting time string to Date format iOS

Tags: ios, date, time, nsdate

I have a string @"21:57" and I want to save it with the same HH:mm format in NSDate. I tried converting it using:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringToConvertFrom];
```

but I'm getting 2000-01-01 21:57:00 +0000 instead of 21:57.

Comment: Sounds right to me.  (Remember, an NSDate object contains no timezone or format -- it always displays in the same format and in UTC/GMT.)

Comment: If you just want a time string then why convert it to an `NSDate`? An `NSDate` is a full timestamp. You will always get a date and time unless you format the output using an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: I want to create an array of objects in which one property is the time I'm converting. Then I want to use predicate to find the object with time greater than a particular time.

Comment: You should take a look at `NSDateComponents` class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html